# PHP 5.3 Dynamically instantiating a class without setting a variable first

Tags: php, oop, class

OK, this has been a personal bugbear of mine for quite some time. Say I have a class.

```
class One {
    public $class = 'Two';
    public $member = 'member';
}

class Two {
    public $member = 'Hey there';

    function __construct() {
        print 'Created';
    }
}

$one = new One();

// case 1: works
$two_class = $one->class;
$two = new $two_class();

// case 2: fails
$two = new {$one->class}();
```

Is there any way to instantiate a class from a class memeber without first assigning the name to a variable? I die a little inside every time I want to create a class dynamically from a property, and I have to populate a variable first. Can anyone explain to me technically why this doesn't work when:

```
print $two->{$one->method}
```

Will happily print 'Hey there'?

Comment: Technically you don't need the ()'s to start that new class.  Also, try assigning it to a variable $new_one = $one->class;

$two = new $new_one();

Comment: I would always discourage you to do anything like this. Simply because you are nto sure whether the given class has the functionality you think it has... It's a maintenance horror! Rather just create a function that creates an object based on the value of the string like function GetMeMyClass($input) { switch ($input) { case 'One': return new One(); case 'Two': return new Two(); default: die("Invalid class given in GetMeMyClass"); } }

Comment: @bkwint I wasn't after your personal preference when it comes to OOP. I just wanted a solution to the question posed. Thanks for your thoughts though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$two = new $one->class();
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/64iCiWn2

But you gonna get big trouble if `$one->class()` is function - it may be confusing, but same thing will happen if if `$two_class` become function